# How to manage state in react during react-router redirects

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example, say i have a child component (the row of a table) which has in its state a 'rating' key, with the value set to '0' in the constructor.

In getDerivedStateFromProps and ComponentDidMount, the rating is set to this.props.rating. so far so good.

Now the user sets a new rating, state is updated, the query to mysql is dispatched, and everything is good. But then the user clicks a Link (react-router-dom) to the same page they are already on. React updates all the components, but since the higher level component has not changed, it does not query the database again for the songs, and therefore the same set of songs is passed down as props, along with the old rating.

my question is simple: should the higher level component query the database each time the user redirects to the component? if so, is there a lifecycle method for this, since props aren't changing? or should the query for the new set of songs be sent each time the user selects a rating? the latter seems like the correct approach, but also inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ["lift your state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so that it lives in the nearest common ancestor to all components that will need to access it. When you update your rating, you need to update the state in the higher level component, *not* the child component. The child component should be mostly presentational - it takes in a rating to display and provides a callback for updating it. But the actual updating and mySql interaction should happen at the higher ancestor level and get passed down through props.

Remember: [the data flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down)